# Mongodb: find documents with array field that contains more than one SAME specified value

Tags: mongodb

There is three documents in collection test:

```
// document 1
{
    "id": 1,
    "score": [3,2,5,4,5]
}

// document 2
{
    "id": 2,
    "score": [5,5]
}

// document 3
{
    "id": 3,
    "score": [5,3,3]
}
```

I want to fetch documents that score field contains [5,5].

query:

```
db.test.find( {"score": {"$all": [5,5]}} )
```

will return document 1, 2 and 3, but I only want to fetch document 1 and 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please can you clarify your expected result - you state "I want to fetch documents that score field contains [5,5]" - the only doc you have with [5,5] is document 2. But you then say "only want to fetch document 1 and 2."

Comment: SorryMy excepted result is: document that has at least two "5" score

Comment: In that case, please see my answer below

Comment: My fault, I mean I want to fetch documents that score field contains at least two "5". So I want to fetch document 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your problem I personally think mongodb not supported yet this kind of query. If any one knows about how to find this using mongo query they defiantly post answers here.

But I think this will possible using mongo [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method, so below code will match your criteria

```
    db.collectionName.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    var scoreCounts = {};
    var arr = myDoc.score;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var num = arr[i];
    scoreCounts[num] = scoreCounts[num] ? scoreCounts[num] + 1 : 1;
    }
    if (scoreCounts[5] >= 2) { //scoreCounts[5] this find occurrence of 5  
    printjsononeline(myDoc);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I have read mongodb manual for half day, and almost ensure mongodb not supported that.
As you say, the best way for me, is to filter the result by programming.

Answer (score 0):

Changed in version 2.6.

The $all is equivalent to an $and operation of the specified values; i.e. the following statement:

`{ tags: { $all: [ "ssl" , "security" ] } }`
is equivalent to:

`{ $and: [ { tags: "ssl" }, { tags: "security" } ] }`

I *think* you need to pass in a nested array -

So try

```
db.test.find( {"score": {"$all": [[5,5]]}} )
```

**Source**

Changed in version 2.6.

When passed an array of a nested array (e.g. [ [ "A" ] ] ), $all can now match documents where the field contains the nested array as an element (e.g. field: [ [ "A" ], ... ]), or the field equals the nested array (e.g. field: [ "A" ]).

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

Comment: your query return only matching document 2, but expected output is document 1 and 2 also . And only `({"score":[5,5]})` return document 2 also no need to nested array

Comment: OP states - "I want to fetch documents that score field contains [5,5]" -this then goes to state "but I only want to fetch document 1 and 2" - ambiguous.

Comment: but OP states also mentioned `return document 1, 2 and 3, but I only want to fetch document 1 and 2`

Comment: I tested this query, only document 2 returned.I think this query is same to `db.test.find( {"score": [5,5]} )`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an aggregation. The first step can use an index on `{ "score" : 1 }` but the rest is hard work.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "score" : 5 } },
    { "$unwind" : "$score" },
    { "$match" : { "score" : 5 } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "sz" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }, // use $first here to include other fields in the results
    { "$match" : { "sz" : { "$gte" : 2 } } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really a hard work ...

In my actual use scene, I want to query documents by any scores, such as:
* document that score contains 2 and 3
* document that score contains 5
* document that score contains at least two 5
and so on.

The first and the second query are easy to do, but the third query is my problem.
I want to find a common (and simple) way to do those, but it seems impossible ...